# Jenkins Groovy shared libraries needed to migrate to Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: groovy, azure-devops, jenkins-pipeline, azure-pipelines

I am currently using Jenkins  for my pipelines and I am also using the shared libraries written in groovy. Now I am planning to move to Azure Devops and use the Azure Pipelines. Is there any way we can use the same groovy pipelines and the shared libraries in Azure Pipelines or do I need to convert all of them to yml files from groovy. And is there any automated way to convert to yml or I need to convert all the groovy to yml manually?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the CI/CD pipelines for your project to Azure DevOps, you need to set up the pipelines on Azure DevOps following the syntax supported in Azure Pipelines. If you want to set up the YAML pipelines, you can reference the documents about "[**YAML schema**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/?view=azure-pipelines)".

For the libraries required in your project:

- If the libraries are built and maintained by yourself, you can build and publish the libraries to a Maven feed on Azure Artifacts. For more details, you can reference the documents about "[**Maven packages**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-maven?view=azure-devops)".
- If the libraries are shared by others, you can publish the library files to a universal feed. For more details, you can reference the documents about "[**Universal packages**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops)".

After above, in the CI/CD pipelines on Azure DevOps, you can restore the packages from the Artifact feed to your project.

Comment: My Shared libraries are in groovy as they were used in the Jenkins groovy file. Can I use the same groovy libraries or should i migrate them into yml?